# How do I turn off the webex preview?

Tags: webex

When I send someone a webex link, it automatically adds a large picture and preview which I have to x out of each and every time.   How can I turn this off??

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please [edit] to clarify ***where*** you are seeing this preview.